# What does types like "clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq" mean in clojure?

Tags: clojure

In clojure REPL, when I type

```
(type (seq [0 1 2 3]))
```

and evaluate it, I got "clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq", but "clojure.lang.PersistentVector" itself is a class in clojure. Why there is "$ChunkedSeq" with it and what does the notation "$" mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $ means that `ChunkedSeq` is a class defined inside [PersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java). As for what a chunked seq is, see [this blog post from four years ago](http://blog.fogus.me/2010/01/22/de-chunkifying-sequences-in-clojure/), when Clojure 1.1 came out:

> Clojure sequence functions are lazy, however with the release of Clojure 1.1 the granularity of this laziness was changed from a 1-at-a-time to a chunk-at-a-time model. In other words, instead of “walking” through a sequence one node at a time, chunked sequences provide a “windowed” viewed on sequences 32-elements wide.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your answer!